# FullTextSearch in wpf ComboBox?

Tags: wpf

I have WPF *ComboBox*, bound to a huge collection of items.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BigCollection}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"/>
```

I have names in my collection:

- Lara Sanders
- Lara Johnson
- etc...

If I enter *"Lara"*, it suggests me the first element, which name starts with *"Lara"*. But if I enter, for example, only *"Johnson"*, it suggests me nothing. Are there any easy ways to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox

Comment: @duDE, looks interesting, but I'm still wondering, whether there is something less comlicated. Something "directly out of a box"?

Comment: @klutch1991 is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S) what you are looking for?

Comment: @BetsonRoy, it seems to be useful for winforms, isn't it? :)

Comment: @klutch1991 oops! my bad sry. ComboBox uses  FindMatchingPrefix() method internally which is private and uses StartsWith.So it seems you cant derive and override it. :/ You would have to create a user control or wpf toolkit's autocomplete box.